# How to fix this command line call in node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, 7zip

```
" 7z a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on -mhe=on -p**** "C:\tmp\test2.zip" "C:\tmp\"test2.txt"
```

I am trying to refactor this code. This creates the test2.zip and zips the test2.txt

This has to be refactored like

```
"7z" a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on -mhe=on -p**** "C:\tmp\test2.zip" "C:\tmp\test2.txt"
```

In nodeJS :

```
var uploadFolder = "C:\tmp\test2.zip";
var fileNmae = "test2.txt";

var command = ' "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on -mhe=on -p**** "' + uploadFolder + '" "C:\\tmp\\"' + fileName ;
```

how to refactor this command so that it looks like this one:

```
   "7z" a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on -mhe=on -p**** "C:\tmp\test2.zip" "C:\tmp\test2.txt"
```

Comment: "This has to be refactored", why ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of wrappers for 7zip that you can find in [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=7zip).  That would probably be easier/better than trying to shell out to a command script from NodeJS.